# php coding for MySQL Join Multiple same id Rows as Columns

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables in a MySQL Database.

persons_info:

```
ID    Name
1     Amit
2     Shalu
```

ere:

```
ID    Loc       Dep_Date      Arr_Date
1     Mumbai    22-Feb-2014   23-Feb-2014
1     Kolkata   28-Mar-2017   29-Mar-2017
1     Delhi     01-Nov-2018   05-Nov-2018
2     Mumbai    22-Feb-2014   23-Feb-2014      1
2     Kolkata   28-Mar-2017   29-Mar-2017
2     Delhi     22-Feb-2014   23-Feb-2014
```

The desired result right from the MySQL query with php coding is:

```
ID    Name    Loc       Arr_Date      Dep_Date
1     Amit    Mumbai    22-Feb-2014   23-Feb-2014
              Kolkata   28-Mar-2017   29-Mar-2017
              Delhi     01-Nov-2018   05-Nov-2018
2     Bob     Mumbai    22-Feb-2014   23-Feb-2014      1
              Kolkata   28-Mar-2017   29-Mar-2017
              Delhi     22-Feb-2014   23-Feb-2014
```

there can be an unlimited number of Loc for each ID.

help please and thanks in advance.

Comment: what you want now ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You might find it helpful to review the site [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Have a look to [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). And don't forget to show us what you've tried so far!

Comment: php coding for the result

Comment: Isn't this virtually the same as you asked yesterday? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49205786/how-to-get-records-of-an-id-from-multiple-sql-tables